# What is the meaning of 'was to be knocked clean through the chimney'?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence

> How often my wife was at me about that projected grand entrance-hall of hers, **which was to be knocked clean through the chimney,**

What is the meaning of the highlighted section?

Comment: Welcome to the site. The question is about a puzzling idiom. There are many uses of "clean" and it is not reasonable to expect a non-native (I assume) speaker to recognise the appropriate idiomatic usage. No source is needed to define the question better. I therefore do not understand the unexplained downvote and have compensated for it.

Answer (score 5):

"clean" is used informally to emphasize that something was done completely, thoroughly ([definition 12](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clean)). "clean through" is similar to "straight through".

It seems that the wife wants to build a grand entrance hall through where the chimney is. The chimney will need to be demolished.

Comment: +1 though I wonder whether *through* may suggest the width of the entrance hall is going to be no more than the width of the chimney.

Comment: @Henry Doubt it. Entrance halls are usually bigger than chimneys.

Comment: That was my concern. When I go straight through something, I expect it to be bigger than me, whether or not I leave a me-sized hole in it.